# .htaccess RewriteRule with 3 Get parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I will user .htaccess file to redirect

```
http://www.example.org/results.php?q=anything&start=0&type=web
```

to

```
http://www.example.org/search/anything/0/web
```

Is that possible ?
At this time, i redirect only the q-GET parameter, with this RewriteRule:

```
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)$ results.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

It still working, but i dont have any idea to rewrite 3 Get-parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ results.php?q=$1&start=$2&type=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^(search)/(.*)/(\d+)/(.*)$ results.php?q=$2&start=$3&type=$4 [L,QSA]
```

little explanation:

when you regex-match with `(.*)` then you can get the matched portion with `$#`where `#` is an incremental number that represent the position of each single match in the chain.

- `search/(.*)` = `search/$1`
- `search/(.*)/(.*)` = `search/$1/$2`
- `search/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)` = `search/$1/$2/$3`